# how to validate a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how to validate a given date

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: if a date is selected it should be greater than today
how to check it in ruby

Comment: when this is a ruby question then why do you flag it as java?

Comment: Java, JavaScript and Ruby in the same project?

Answer (score 3):

Prepare a time object from params and simply check it from Time.now

```
t1 = Time.new(params[:date])

if t1 > Time.now
       # your code 
end
```